# remove my: namespace from fields

Tags: infopath

There is a form and an xml as data source. The xml has no namespace. I got a request to add a new field to the form. 
Now, when I added the new field with Infopath Designer, it also added a namespace: `my:NewField`. For me, this is not a big problem, as the users don't see it, but the xml is used by other processes as well, and there the my: namespace is causing troubles.

I tried the followings:

Exported the form as source files and replaced all "my:" text with "" in text editor.
the result was an error: `schema.xsd#/schema/element[2][@name = 'customer']/complexType[1]/sequence[1]/element[9]
Undeclared XSD element : 'NewField'.`

Also tried to add the new field to the xml itself and refresh fields based on the new xml, but then it also added an unexpected `(Choice group)` to the structure.

How can I either prevent Infopath adding the my: namespace or, if this not possible, remove it later from the template?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could design a new form template using the updated XML. *(I assume this is how this form had been designed originally).*

Form the Info-path designer select

File -> Design a form Template

Then choose "XML or Schema" option and complete the wizard by selecting updated XML file as the data source. All the fields will be available on the data source once you complete the wizard. Then you can drag and drop the fields to the form and complete the design similar to the original form.

You could export the new form as source files and verify the namespace. It should not be there.

Comment: This method also add a (Choice) group to the structure that I cannot remove.

Comment: I removed part of the data and rebuilt the form. Now it looks good. So, the issue was somewhere in the xml.